# How to affect a specific class when button contained in said class is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a list of links which each have their own scores and up/down vote buttons.

When a vote button is clicked, I want to change all the colours in that track's line to green/red.

```
    <ul id = "tracklist">
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link1.com">Track 1</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">10 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link2.com">Track 2</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">5 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link3.com">Track 3</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link4.com">Track 4</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So if I was to click the upvote button of track 2, how could I change the style attributes of it's containing "trackwrap"?

The problem is I don't know how to select just the specific `li` that contains the button that is clicked. I'm pretty new to javascript so this has been a problem knowing what to google so I'm sorry if the question already exists.

The list will be auto-generated so I can't assign ID's to each `li` and use `getElementById`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it this way, Change the class or add CSS to the parent of clicked `.upvote`

```
$(".upvote").click(function(){

   $(this).parent().css({"color":"#0f0"});
   // or $(this).parent().addClass("green");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged your question `jquery`, so I'm guessing you're hooking up the buttons using jQuery, either directly:

```
$(".upvote").on("click", function() {
    // ...
});
// (And similar for downvote)
```

or using delegation (which is what I would use in this case):

```
$("#tracklist").on("click", ".upvote", function() {
    // ...
});
// (And similar for downvote)
```

Either way, within the callback to the handler when the button is clicked, `this` will refer to the button that was clicked. So then `$(this).closest(".trackwrap")` will give you the `.trackwrap` that button is in:

```
var trackwrap = $(this).closest(".trackwrap");
```

...and then you can add/remove classes or whatever to set the color of that `li`.

You *could* also use `.parent`, since the `.trackwrap` is the direct parent of the buttons, but that's fragile: A smallish change to your HTML structure would break it. Using `.closest` will work as long as the button is within the `.trackwrap`, even if you put other elements in-between.

Side note: If you then want to access the `.trackscore` within that specific `.trackwrap`, you can use `find` from the `.trackwrap`:

```
var trackscore = trackwrap.find(".trackscore");
```

Example:

```js
// In this case, I'm using delegated handlers
$("#tracklist").on("click", "button.upvote", function() {
  var trackwrap = $(this).closest(".trackwrap");
  // Here I'm just forcing it green, but you probably have more
  // you want to do, hence the note about .trackscore above
  trackwrap.toggleClass("good", true).toggleClass("bad", false);
});
$("#tracklist").on("click", "button.downvote", function() {
  var trackwrap = $(this).closest(".trackwrap");
  // Here I'm just forcing it red, but you probably have more
  // you want to do, hence the note about .trackscore above
  trackwrap.toggleClass("good", false).toggleClass("bad", true);
});
```

```css
.good {
  background-color: #008000;
}
.bad {
  background-color: #800000;
}
```

```html
<ul id = "tracklist">
  <li class = "trackwrap">
    <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link1.com">Track 1</a>
    <p class = "trackscore">10 points</p>
    <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
    <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
  </li>
  <li class = "trackwrap">
    <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link2.com">Track 2</a>
    <p class = "trackscore">5 points</p>
    <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
    <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
  </li>
  <li class = "trackwrap">
    <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link3.com">Track 3</a>
    <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
    <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
    <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
  </li>
  <li class = "trackwrap">
    <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link4.com">Track 4</a>
    <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
    <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
    <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you click the button you can reference it by `this` or `event.target` in your function. Since the DOM structure is hierarchical the button is actually a child of the `li`. So if you use `parentElement` you will select the correct element.

Demo:

```js
//CODE TO ATTACH CLICK HANDLERS TO ALL BUTTONS
   Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("tracklist").querySelectorAll("button"), function(element){
        element.addEventListener("click", setVote, false);
   });
//

function setVote(e) //e for event;
{
  var voteCount;
  if (e.target.textContent == "+")
    {
      voteCount = 1;
    }
  else
    {
      voteCount = -1;
    }
  
  var parent = e.target.parentElement;  
  parent.querySelector("p.trackscore").textContent = parseInt(parent.querySelector("p.trackscore").textContent) + voteCount + " points";

  if (parseInt(parent.querySelector("p.trackscore").textContent) < 0)
    {
      parent.className = "trackwrap bad";
      }
  else
    {
      parent.className = "trackwrap good";
    }
  
    
}
```

```css
.trackwrap {
  background-color: white;
}

.trackwrap.good {
  background-color: lime;
}

.trackwrap.bad {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul id = "tracklist">
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link1.com">Track 1</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">10 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link2.com">Track 2</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">5 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link3.com">Track 3</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link4.com">Track 4</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery :

```js
$('.upvote').on('click', function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "green");
                    //Also, if you have defined a css class you can use addClass("myclass"); instead of css()
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "tracklist">
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link1.com">Track 1</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">10 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link2.com">Track 2</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">5 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link3.com">Track 3</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
        <li class = "trackwrap">
            <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link4.com">Track 4</a>
            <p class = "trackscore">0 points</p>
            <button class = "upvote" type="button">+</button>
            <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add an onclick listener to your buttons:

```
    <li class = "trackwrap">
        <a  class = "tracklink" href="https://www.link1.com">Track 1</a>
        <p class = "trackscore">10 points</p>
        <button class = "upvote" onclick="upvote(this)" type="button">+</button>
        <button class = "downvote" type="button">-</button>
    </li>
```

Then in the function:

```
 function upvote(btn) {
     var parentElement = btn.parentElement;

     // use parentElement to edit DOM
     parentElement.style.color = "red";
 }
```